# Ansible playbook to find particular java process and kill

Tags: java, jar, find, ansible, microservices

I'm working on deploying microservices with ansible-playbook right now. And all of the microservices uses `java -jar` command to deploy. Right now I'm trying to write an ansible playbook to find and kill dependent java -jar process before deploying other one.

I'm running out of ideas here. I was thinking of creating a script in init.d for java deamon. But, if i do that and stop service, it would stop all the java processes which i wouldn't want.

**Output for** `ps -ef | grep java`

> **root**     28330     1  1 13:52 ?        00:00:56 *java -jar -DCONFIG_FOLDER=/opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/config /opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/enrollment-vehicle-dal-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*
>
> **root**     29143     1  2 14:22 ?        00:00:49 *java -jar -DCONFIG_FOLDER=/opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/config  /opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/enrollment-vehicle-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*
>
> **root**     29879     1  2 14:23 ?        00:00:48 *java -jar -DCONFIG_FOLDER=/opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/config  /opt/app/microservices/deploy/dal-core/enrollment-account-dal-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*
>
> **root**     31093     1  3 14:28 ?        00:01:04 *java -jar -DCONFIG_FOLDER=/opt/app/microservices/deploy/listener/config  /opt/app/microservices/deploy/listener/enrollment-account-listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar*
>
> asadmin  31208 18879  0 14:57 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java

In the above scenario, If i happen do deploy enrollment-account-dal-core again, I should 1st kill enrollment-account-listener (pid:31093) and then enrollment-account-dal-core (pid:29879).

I have one playbook for all of the microservices so I won't be able to hard code it either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I hope that `pattern` parameter in `service` module will solve your problem. You can find documentation [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html#synopsis). I think your Ansible task will look like this code:

```
- name: Killing enrollment-account-listener
  service:
    name: enrollment-account-listener
    state: stopped
    pattern: enrollment-account-listener
```

Documentation says, if service with given name doesn't response to service status command, then find `pattern` in output of ps command. If the string is found, the service will be assumed to be running.

If it won't work, you can still use `command` or `shell` module to find solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback 32cupo. I'm sorry I didn't get a chance to use the playbook module, However, it looks perfect. Yes I used the shell module to solve the issue. Something like this: "kill $(ps aux | grep -i 'enrollment-account' | awk '{print $2}')" ...........This command would grep for the string "enrollment-account" and kill the process ID :) ..